# Dynamically change fragment

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

How can I add a view into a fragment?

Via:

```
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_tab, null);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setText("sample text");
            ll.addView(tv);

            setContentView(ll);
```

I can add a text. Works fine for an activity. But how can I dynamically change the layout of a fragment. If I try with the version above the tree tabs I got are not swipable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try using [`Fragment.getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getView())

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_tab, null);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("sample text");
ll.addView(tv);

// now locate the fragment you want to add a view too by its tag name
SomeFragment someFragment = (SomeFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("someTag");
if (someFragment != null){
    someFragment.getView().addView(ll);
}
```

Comment: And how can I define the Fragment Tag before?

Comment: in your [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)'s usage of `add()' or  `replace()' method.. or in the xml layout